# Swig wrapping GLM library

Tags: c++, lua, swig, glm-math

I am working on a 2D game engine at the moment and have hit a stumbling block whilst implementing the LUA scripting / Interpreter.

I'm using SWIG and have got the basics all working fine.

In the engine I use the GLM (OpenGL Mathematics Libary http://glm.g-truc.net/) for all Vector and Matrix related areas.

I really need to expose glm (at a basic level) to the via SWIG to LUA so I can call methods in LUA like:

```
actor:GetPosition()  <- Which returns a glm::vec2
```

GLM is quite a complex library (possibly an understatement lol) and I do not require the whole thing exposed, that would be ridiculous amounts of work I assume. I simply want to be able to access the xy components of the glm::vec2 class.

I'm sure this must be easy as SWIG doesn't require a full class definition and there must be a way to let SWIG just assume that the glm::vec2 class just has x,y params.

I'm not sure If using Proxy classes in SWIG is the way to do this ? or some other method ? I'm quite new to LUA integration and SWIG also.

One route I really don't want to go down is ditching GLM and writing my own Vector/Matrix library which is much more simple, no templates etc and I can then simply wrap with SWIG, but I feel this would be a waste of time and I would ultimately end up with a less powerful Math Library :(.

Thanks in advance and I can provide more info if necessary.

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want to access the x,y *and* z component of a *2-dimensional* vector?

Comment: Thanks for that catch, edited my Question, simple typo meant x,y

Comment: Do you need to use SWIG? I found it really cumbersome to use especially in regards of template classes/functions, and in my opinion, there are way better alternatives. (SWIG is most interesting when you want to create bindings to many different scripting languages, imho)

Comment: Im by no means dedicated to SWIG,  What would you personally suggest as an alternative ? I've used Luabind before (years ago) but had recently heard not so good speak of it on various forums, that plus the fact it doesn't seem to have been updated in a while.

Comment: Luabind is what I would have suggested, and I only had positive experiences with it. I'll try to answer your question with luabind, for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution in [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html) would look like this:

```
#include <luabind/luabind.hpp>


extern "C" int init(lua_State* L)
{
    using namespace luabind;
    using namespace glm;

    open(L);

    module(L)
    [
        class_<dvec2>("dvec2")
            .def_readwrite("x", &dvec2::x)
            .def_readwrite("y", &dvec2::y)
    ];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I took your suggestion on board and removed Swig and decided to attempt using Luabind however it seems due to it's age, lack of support and my incompetance that I'm unable to get it built on OSX leaving me stuck now on whether to pour more time into trying to build Luabind or find another more modern / maintained library.

Comment: I found a "Maintained" version of Luabind here : https://github.com/rpavlik/luabind
It is forked/maintained by RPavlik on Github, and he's created a much more uptodate CMake build as well as fixing several bits more recently.

Answer (score 2):

The big problem with GLM is that its vector types use things that have dubious C++ validity. Things that many compilers will *allow*, but are not allowed by the standard. SWIG uses its own parser to work, so it's going to have a hard time making heads or tails of GLM's definitions.

In a case like this, I would suggest using something like Luabind rather than SWIG. It gives a bit more fine-grained control in such circumstances, and it has the benefit of not using its own parser. Granted, you could effectively rewrite the prototypes for the important parts of GLM in your .swig file.